# Как из txt файла (с помощью ключевых слов) вытащить нужный мне фрагмент текста и сохранить его в другом txt файле

Tags: python, парсер

У меня есть txt файл

```
zdfnhgblrb165415614
.,fl;djgikddghbldkg
KLDFHGIUDTOG

ХЛЕБ:
15 внегор
шт.
sfdg  ку5ек6г
сыр: 5к шт.  укрео
ячсамчи
колбаса:
4шт.


Молоко
1
шт. 

варпопапв4356743
```

как сделать так, чтобы python выделял нужный фрагмент текста форматировал его и сохранял в новом txt файле?

Результат:

```
Хлеб: 15 шт.
Сыр: 5 шт.
Колбаса: 4 шт.
Молоко: 1 шт.
```

Comment: Необходимо формализовать критерии "нужности"

Comment: какой-то очень надуманный пример порчи данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить следующий пример, покрывающий почти все случаи.

Если выделить критерий поиска `"Название": "количество"`, то можно следующей регуляркой найти все, кроме молока:

```
import re

text = """
zdfnhgblrb165415614
.,fl;djgikddghbldkg
KLDFHGIUDTOG

ХЛЕБ:
15 внегор
шт.
sfdg  ку5ек6г
сыр: 5к шт.  укрео
ячсамчи
колбаса:
4шт.


Молоко
1
шт. 

варпопапв4356743
"""

matches = re.findall(r'([а-яА-Яеё]+):.+?(\d+)', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)  # [('ХЛЕБ', '15'), ('сыр', '5'), ('колбаса', '4')]

for name, number in matches:
    print('{}: {} шт.'.format(name.title(), number))
```

Консоль:

```
Хлеб: 15 шт.
Сыр: 5 шт.
Колбаса: 4 шт.
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант улучшения кода, который открывает один файл, находит все нужные данные, сохраняет в другой:

```
import re

f = open('file.txt', 'r')
text = f.read()
nf = open('file_new.txt', 'w')
matches = re.findall(r'([а-яА-Яеё]+:|Молоко).(\d+).', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
# [('ХЛЕБ:', '15'), ('сыр:', '5'), ('колбаса:', '4'), ('Молоко', '1')]

for name, number in matches:
    name_title = name.title()
    if ":" not in name_title:
        name_title += ":"
    nf.write('{} {} шт.'.format(name_title, number) + '\n')
f.close()
nf.close()
```

Содержимое файла:

```
Хлеб: 15 шт.
Сыр: 5 шт.
Колбаса: 4 шт.
Молоко: 1 шт.
```